# CouchBase Lite Mobile Schema Design

Tags: couchbase-lite

I am unsure if I am creating a proper schema for a CouchBase mobile database. Here is an example of a schema for 1 user's mobile app:

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "firstname": "Jim",
            "lastname": "terry",
            "addresses": [
                {
                    "address": "123 Way",
                    "zipcode": "65432"
                },
                ...
            ],
            "activities": [
                {
                    "steps": 500
                },
                {
                    "sleep_hours": 2
                },
                ...
            ],
            "posts": [
                {
                    "subject": "Hello",
                    "body": "World"
                },
                ...
            ]
        },
       ...
    ]
}
```

A mobile app could have 1 to many users on a device. The server database could hold many users that the app would only have access to. What I am having a hard time wrapping my head around is whether this is a good data model for a couchbase app. I have denormalized all of the data associated to a user under a user schema. My questions are as follows:

1. What happens if activity gets really large for a user and posts gets really large? When you make an update to activity does it have to save the whole document which could create a performance option when only one piece of data on the user gets updated? Does the database break up these arrays as separate documents from the user?
2. Is it best practice to store the data in activities in this fashion? In the example, both objects are an activity but they contain completely separate data.
3. Is this the most efficient model? One example of a change might be instead of having a generic "activities":[] creating "step_activities" and "sleep_activities"?

Comment: It's a very broad question (but certainly not off-topic!), however I think it's safe to say that you may find more suitable reactions to it on either http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ or http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Michal - this would get closed on Progs as "Too Broad."

Comment: @Michal: There's not enough information here to provide a meaningful answer.

Comment: I believe it's much better now. Please review for reopen.